# Using the $\cot (\pi z)$ to find $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I'm trying to prove the result that $$\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\pi^2/6$$ using cotangents and residue theory.

I know that $\sum f(n)=-$Sum of residues of $\pi \cot (\pi z)f(z)$ at the poles of $f(z)$

$$\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$.
 Now the only pole is $z=0$ which is a double pole, but when I evaluate:

$$\frac{d}{dz} \pi \cot (\pi z) \frac{1}{z^2}(z^2)=\infty$$

Can somebody show me **why my method doesn't work**?

Comment: You can have a look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axQqExF7NsU&index=8&list=PL32446FDD4DA932C9

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks, could you point out why my method isn't working?